# Change Usercontrol textblock from MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, binding

Hi I got user control called "Order" and In "Order" control, I got another user control "Status". Then, I put Order Control into the Mainwindow. When the users change language, I write as below.

```
// change culture info.
this.Order.lbl_test.Content = resBundle.GetString("Resources", "Order.Label.Content.Test");
```

I also have one textblock in "Status" UserControl. How could I change this textblock text from MainWindow like I changed Order control lable?

Comment: You should use MVVM.  bind the text of the Order.Label to a property of Order View Model.  then you could set the property of OrderViewModel from the Window.  Then call OnPropertyChanged on the property.  The text would be automatically updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign an x:Name (e.g., "StatusText") to the TextBlock in your Status UserControl.  Then add a property to your Order control called StatusText:

```
public string StatusText
{
    get { return Status.StatusText.Text; }
    set { Status.StatusText.Text = value; }
}
```

You can now say:

```
this.Order.StatusText = resBundle.GetString("Resources", "SomeLabel");
```